# Java android API 30 do not show photo in ACTION_VIEW

Tags: java, android

```
Intent showPhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        showPhotoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content:" + getItem(position).getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");
    } else {
        showPhotoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:" + getItem(position).getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");

    }
```

In Android 10 this intent do not display a photo and I do not know why